# ERROR Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains an invalid key ($key) in property

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

im a newbie to angular and I'm trying  to implement add-to-cart functionality on an angular project.
here is the function that adds to cart:

```
  async addToCart(product: Productsobj) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.db.object(
      "/shopping-carts/" + cartId + "/items/" + product.$key
    );
    item$
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((p: any) => {
        if (p) item$.update({ quantity: p.quantity + 1 });
        else item$.set({ product: product, quantity: 1 });
      });
  }
```

here is the error :

> core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Reference.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($key) in property 'shopping-carts.-Lw2GnUrgt9nMyNKznlW.items.-KrqgOLs07ZkbapP4EGi.product'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

i tried changing the function as :

```
  async addToCart(product: Productsobj) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.db.object(
      "/shopping-carts/" + cartId + "/items/{{product.$key}}"// changed product.$key
    );
    item$
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((p: any) => {
        if (p) item$.update({ quantity: p.quantity + 1 });
        else item$.set({ product: product, quantity: 1 });
      });
   }
```

now getting the error as :

> core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "/shopping-carts/-Lw2GnUrgt9nMyNKznlW/items/{{product.$key}}". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

how do i unwrap the `product.$key` properly?

**edit:**
the product argument is an object : console.log(product)
[image: product]

after changing `product:product` to `productName:product.title` errors are gone , firebase shows:
[image: firebase]

**is there a way to get the whole object in firebase?**

Comment: can you update the question with the value of the product parameter being received by addToCart func.

Comment: yes i have updated @Ramesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let key = product["$key"];
let item$ = this.db.object("/shopping-carts/" + cartId + "/items/" + key);
```

Use brackets to access the property `$key`. Also it's better if you change the property `$key` to just `key`

Comment: yes i tried that  same error, it seems the problem is not the path but  ` item$.set({ product: product, quantity: 1 });  ` here the argument product doesnt unwrap . is there a way to send an object as a whole to firebase . edit: it works when i  change `product:product.$key ` or  `product:product.title`

Comment: but i want the whole object to be sent to firebase. is there a way to do it? @peter

Comment: if i add `product:product`  gives me error otherwise if  `product:product.title` or `product:product.category ` runs fine without errors but i only get the said data ( ie title , category ,etc) in firebase . i want the whole product object in firebase. check question for updated pics @peter

Comment: @GeorgeMenezes you can do `set({productName:product.title,productCategory:product.category, productKey : product.key})`

Comment: if you add the whole object, then when retrieving you should do `product.product.category`

Answer (score 1):

Use `product.payload.val()` to set the product attribute to the product object as follows:

```js
async addToCart(product){
  let cartId= await this.getOrCreateCartId();
  let item$=  this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + product.key);
  item$.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item:any) => {
    if(item!=null) {
      item$.set({product: product.payload.val(), quantity: item.quantity + 1})
    }
    else item$.set({product: product.payload.val(), quantity: 1});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for the definition of Productsobj interface:

```
export interface Productsobj
{
   key: string; 
   title: string; 
   price: number; 
   category: string; 
   imageUrl: string;
}
```

i.e instead of using "$key" use "key". With this the following code works

```
async addToCart(product: Productsobj) {
   const cartId = await this.addOrGetCartId();
   const item$ = this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + product.key);
   item$.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe( (item:any) => {
      if (item) item$.update({quantity: item.quantity + 1});
      else item$.update({product: product, quantity: 1});
 });
}
```

Firebase does not allow you to have keys starting with $ character. If you try to add a new object in database (using firebase console) with key as "$key", following error is flagged:
'Path contains invalid characters'. This is why you are getting error in your Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

**Before (With Error)**

```
  async addToCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.$key as string);
    item$
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((item: any) => {
        if (item == null)
          item$.set({
            product: product,
            quantity: 1,
          });
        else item$.update({ quantity: item.quantity + 1 });
      });
  }
```

**After (Without Error)**

```
  async addToCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.$key as string);
    item$
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((item: any) => {
        if (item == null)
          item$.set({
            product: {
              title: product.title,
              category: product.category,
              price: product.price,
              imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
            },
            quantity: 1,
          });
        else item$.update({ quantity: item.quantity + 1 });
      });
  }
```

just change the Implicit product object to Explicit product object